# NodeJS detect if user doesn`t touch a button for a minute

Tags: node.js, if-statement, detect

I want to when the user doesn`t press a button for more than a minute the script just stop run for him.
The only way would be puttin a code in every single button to add time to the clock and if the clock reaches 0 the script stop for the person.

Someone have a better way?
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to "simulate button presses" with node.js?  That's a server language, not a client/UI language.  Are perhaps talking about a website being served by a node.js server?

Answer (score 0):

Create a timeout, and each time the user touches the button, reset the timer. Within the function of the timeout, stop your script.

Creating a timeout:

```
var myVar = setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
```

Clearing your timeout and resetting it:

```
var clearTimeout(myVar);
myVar = setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
```

Comment: Worked nice! But how can I do that the script just stop running for a specif person? I`m making a game and when a person is ofline he have to be kicked from the game

Comment: Add a function to your script to stop it. Call this function from the callback function within the setTimout or have it be the function passed to setTimeout

Comment: I used the function process.exit() but this kill all the process, but I`ll search for this, thanks a lot :)